# Check for img load multiple times with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have server script which generates thumbnails of uploaded files.
Bu sometimes upload process takes some time because some files are about 60 MB PSD files.

Thumbnail creation process work as standalone service and completion of upload doesnt mean thumnail created.

I dont know if thumbnail is created at the point of upload complete but I know the name of thumbnail file which will be created.

So my question,

After upload complete I want to check if file is created 5 times with 5 seconds interval. If none of this requests returns with success I want to show a default img thumbnail.

This is what I have for now...

```
...

    this.thumbImgTryNum = 0;

    this._setPreviewImageSafeSrc = function (path, ext) {

        this.$fileThumb.attr('src', path).error(function () {

            if (thisPanel.thumbImgTryNum <= options.thumbImgMaxTry) {

                setTimeout(function () {

                    console.log('ERROR : ' + thisPanel.thumbImgTryNum);

                    thisPanel._setPreviewImageSafeSrc(path, ext);

                    thisPanel.thumbImgTryNum++;

                }, 5000);

            }
        });
    }

...
```

I can not find a way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.AJAX:

```
   var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
        .done(function() {
            // image exists
        })
        .fail(function() {
            // image does not exist
        });
```